# How to take screenshot of map in CesiumJS?

Tags: angularjs, cesiumjs

I'm using CesuimJS (http://cesiumjs.org/) to present map.
I want to take a screenshot of part of the map.

I tried using Three.js (http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/) but failed to take a screenshot

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use ThreeJS.

You can use the canvas function toDataUrl.

```
viewer.render();
viewer.canvas.toDataUrl();
```

toDataUrl returns url that can be used to get the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```js
viewer.render();
viewer.canvas.toDataURL();
```